# Calling Bearer Api Authentication from .NET MAUI

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, maui

I used Bearer Authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC:

https://quizzingapiauth.azurewebsites.net/api/Questions

https://github.com/KalyanAllam/QuizzingApiAuth

I tried the below code and I get an error:

> Internal Server Error, HTTP Status Code :500

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) 
{
    string url = "https://localhost:44361/api/Employee";
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    // System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> result = client.GetAsync(uri);

    string input = "test:pass";

    byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Convert.ToBase64String(array));

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> result = client.GetAsync(uri);

    if (result.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> response = result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        employees = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Employee>>(response.Result);
     }
 }
```

Comment: "its giving error" - what error is it giving?  That is highly relevant information you should include in your post

Comment: I am getting "Internal Server Error", Status Code :500

Comment: That is, as the name implies, an error on the **server**.  You need to look at the server logs to determine the problem